# Suggestions for a command line search-and-replace tool on Windows

Tags: windows, replace

I am looking for a Windows tool (exe) or Python script which can be used on the command line to search and replace strings in text files recursively in a source code tree. I am trying to avoid the custom syntax of sed/awd like linux tools. It needs to be automated, therefore it needs to be command line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think WinGrep may meet your needs.  I believe it can be run from the command line.  Link: [www.wingrep.com](http://www.wingrep.com/)

Comment: Note that this product no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

A little pricey, but [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com) has a command line interface or so the manual says.

Answer (score 1):

There is fnr.exe, which is a lightweight utility that supports command line.  It doesn't have as many features as grep, but it makes it easy to generate command line script by providing all the parameters in windows form.  It is available from here:
http://findandreplace.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

NotePad++ worked great.  Free add-in.
Search - Find in files...

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i%TEMP%\* "s/regexp/replacement/g" *.txt
```

Backup files will be in temp directory.
Sed can be easily downloaded with chocolatey:
https://chocolatey.org/packages/sed